# Are targeted writes to documents in Cosmos DB less expensive than larger writes?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

If I have a giant document in Cosmos DB, say 1MB or so (so [50% as big as current max](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45355821/1028230)), and it's a reasonably complex object model...

- How expensive is a *targeted write* (that is, a partial update) to a well-nested property vs. a complete document rewrite?
- Is there *any* level at which a "less than complete" rewrite is cheaper than just blasting in a new [though with much of the same data as before] document?
- Does Cosmos even do less than complete resource updates? ([My sources say no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_8-Ball#Possible_answers), and some targeted googling hasn't produced anything to the contrary.)

That is, **is there any advantage to trying to selectively update existing documents, and, if so, how can I utilize and measure that advantage?**

> **Motivation:** If there's not a way to efficiently update, and I want to make lots of writes -- as many as reads (relative scale) -- it sounds like I might want to write to lots of smaller docs that I eventually stitch into an icier/more persistent store later.
>
> If there is a way to do partial updates to docs, I don't have to overengineer like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos does not currently support PATCH (or target writes as I believe you're calling them). So your only option is to replace the whole document. We are investigating this support, though.

It's worth thinking about how you could split your document into smaller chunks if you're going to be doing lots of small updates. One approach I like is having one "parent" document which links to "child" documents. This also allows you to grow your content over 2MB since its not tied to the per-document limit.

Comment: Ah, you mean linked docs within the same collection. Yep, that's what I was approximating with "*it sounds like I might want to write to lots of smaller docs that I eventually stitch into an icier/more persistent store later*", but [painfully obvious in retrospect] simpler. Thanks. Re: PATCHing -- [Do it](https://tenor.com/view/doit-gif-4445206). ;^)

Comment: "but *this is* simpler"