# MongoDB Using Java , How do I filter on 2 fields of the same document

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Using Mongo DB (Azure cosmos DB) and i need to filter out objects based on 2 
fields inside the documents

Here is an example class:

```
class Event{
   public long startTime;
   public long endTime;
}
```

I need to find all events that their startTime==endTime

In sql i would do

```
Select * from Events where startTime=endTime
or
Select * from Events where startTime!=endTime
```

How do i do it in mongo?

```
collection.find(???).first();
```

Comment: Hi,Maayan. What's the meaning of the sql :`Select * from Events where startTime=endTime
or
Select * from Events where startTime!=endTime`

Comment: You just want to filter with one condition: startTime==endTime??

Comment: just gave 2 examples. one for getting all the events that their startTime equals their endTime and the second is the opposite

Comment: ok,maybe you could refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With native mongo filter operator,you could use `find` and `aggregate` to filter  `startTime==endTime` :

**find**:

```
db.test.find({
    "$where": "this.fields1 == this.fields2"
});
```

**aggregate**:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            fields1: 1,
            fields2: 1,
            difference: { $eq: ["$fields1", "$fields2"]}
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            difference: true
        },
    }
]);
```

However,based on the statements in official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#unsupported-operators):

> The $where and the $eval operators are not supported by Azure Cosmos
>   DB.

You could refer to the [aggregation pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#aggregation-pipelinea) which is preview version.

Or you could try to use [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#benefits-of-using-server-side-programming) to select the documents and loop it for comparing the filter columns,then return the desired data.(for reference packages :https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize)

Comment: What will be the Java version of it?
AggregateIterable<Event> aggregate = collection.aggregate(
    Arrays.asList(
      Aggregates.project(
        Projections.fields(
          Projections.include("fSeen"),
          Projections.include("lSeen"),
          Projections.computed(
                                  "difference",
                                  Filters.eq("fSeen","lSeen")                                  
                          )
          ))
      ,
    Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("difference",true)))
  );

Comment: @MaayanHope This is the code of java mongo db client package?

Comment: com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable

Comment: @MaayanHope I'm afraid that you can't treat cosmos db mongo api as normal mongo db, it just supports a subset of the MongoDB features. Please refer to my previous thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882764/cosmosdb-sql-api-vs-mongodb-api-which-one-to-use-for-my-scenario/52886759#52886759

Comment: @MaayanHope So,maybe you could try to use stored procedure as a workaround? Then execute the stored procedure in your java code. It could work.